# Attribute language error

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, attribute-table, internationalization

I have a data for a project and the attributes had been written in Arabic and this what I found, how can I repair it and get the Arabic texts?

I am using ArcGIS 10.4

[image]

Comment: which software are you using?

Comment: i am using ArcGIS 10.4

Comment: Do you know files’s encoding?

Comment: no i don't know it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using shapefile, and unfortunately shapefile does not support Unicode by default as explained in the [FAQ: Does ArcGIS Desktop support Unicode?](http://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000007115). I will quote the following:

> Currently personal geodatabases and file geodatabases are the only
>   data format that supports Unicode by default. It is even possible to
>   store and display characters of multiple languages in a single
>   personal or file geodatabase. If the characters are not displayed
>   correctly, verify that the font is set to Unicode font, such as
>   Tahoma.
>
> **Shapefiles also support Unicode, but not by default**. To enable Unicode
>   support in shapefiles, a registry key needs to be modified.

So you can follow this [Article: How To: Read and write shapefile and dBASE files encoded in various code pages](http://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000013192) to modify the registry to enable Unicode support

**Or** another method that you can use is to `Change System locale` in your Windows using the following steps:

**Notes**

- You must be logged in with an account that has administrative
  privileges in order to change the system locale.
- The appropriate language packs should be installed on the operating
  system.

*View the System Locale settings for Windows*

1. Click Start, then Control Panel
2. Click Clock, Language and Region

   - Windows 10, Windows 8: Click Region
   - Windows 7: Click Region and Language
   - Windows XP: Click Regional and Language Options
3. The Region and Language options dialog appears.
4. Click the Administrative tab
5. On Windows XP, click the Advanced tab
6. If there is no Advanced tab, then you are not logged in with administrative privileges.
7. Under the Language for non-Unicode programs section, click Change system locale and select the desired language **(Arabic Language)**.
8. Click OK
9. Restart the computer to apply the change.
10. Start ArcGIS and load the shapefile again and check if the Arabic fonts can be read properly in the attribute table.
11. I advice you to export the shapefile to a Personal Geodatabase or a File Geodatabase to read the Arabic fonts properly without doing the above long process again if you want restore the locale settings to its original settings.

Comment: it worked well, thank you very much for this great answer

Comment: You are welcome. Please up vote the answer, if you didn't do so, so that it can help others who face the same issue.